# my jquery autocomplete after append to div not able to select

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

i use from jquery autocomplete, and append data into a div for customize them, my data will show in div but these are no selectable , i want to select my ideal item :(

this is my code:
html code

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="../Style/ucStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../Style/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="divMain">
    <div id="divFind">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSearch" CssClass="textBox" autocomplete="false" >        
        </asp:TextBox>
        <div id="divFindResult" class="ui-widget results">
            <div id="divLines" class="ui-widget-content results">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <ul id="ulLines"></ul>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div id="divBusStops" class="ui-widget-content">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <ul id="ulBusStops"></ul>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfItem" runat="server" />
    </div>
</div>
```

js code :

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        var thing = $('#<%=txtSearch.ClientID%>').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Services/BusWebService.asmx/GetRouteInfo",
                    data: "{ 'param': '" + request.term + "' }",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                itemid: item.split(',')[0],
                                itemtype: item.split(',')[1],
                                label: item.split(',')[2]
                            }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $('#<%=hfItem.ClientID%>').val(ui.item.itemid + ',' + ui.item.itemtype + ',' + ui.item.label);
                //$("form").submit();
            },
            search: function (event, ui) {
                $("#ulBusStops").empty();
                $("#ulLines").empty();
            },
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $("#divFindResult").css("display", "block");
            },
            close: function (event, ui) {
                $("#divFindResult").css("display", "none");
                $("#ulBusStops").empty();
                $("#ulLines").empty();

            }
        });
        thing.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            if (item.itemtype == 1) {
                return $("<li></li>")
                    .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                    .append("<a class='results'><img src='../images/line_icon.png' height='16' width='16'>" + " " + item.label + "</a>")
                .appendTo($('#ulLines'));

            } else {
                return $("<li></li>")
                   .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                   .append("<a class='results'><img src='../images/bus_icon.png' height='16' width='16'>" + " " + item.label + "</a>")
                .appendTo($('#ulBusStops'));
            }
        };
    });
```

i see results in my div but these are not selectable, anyone can help me??

Comment: if you have found any solution to this please post it. I am facing the same problem.

Comment: hi dear @chanchalpardeshi
i found answer for this problem by using css classes
u can set a class for items when mouse over occures change class by jquery selectors 
but i dont remember that details bcz this problem was for two years ago  
good luck !

Comment: Make sure you've imported the stylesheet correctly 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">`

Comment: tanx alot @ruth young